# How can I correctly obtain the value of response headers in WSO2 ESB (the response obtained after a call mediator)

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I am pretty new in **WSO2 ESB** and I have the following problem.

In my code I have a **call mediator** performing a request towards an external web service (represented by an endpoint), then the result obtained by this exterla web service (an XML document) is put into a **mesage store**.

Something like this:

```
<!-- Call GLIS API -->
<call>
    <endpoint key="transferFromGLISAPI"/>
</call>
<log level="full"/>

<!-- Store result into transferFromResultMessageStore  -->
<store messageStore="transferFromResultMessageStore"/>
```

It works fine, the external web service represented by the **transferFromGLISAPI** endpoint is correctly called and the retrieved XML document is correctly put into my message store.

My problem is that, after the **call mediator** execution I want retrieve also some headers value from the received response.

If I perform the call to this exterla web service using **cURL** infact I have something like this:

```
$ curl -i -k https://XXX.YYY.ZZZ.WWW/glisapi/v1/pgrfas?doi=10.0155/1M
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   103  100   103    0     0    164      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   164HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 11 Jul 2017 07:51:08 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Rate-Limit-Limit: 3
X-Rate-Limit-Remaining: 2
X-Rate-Limit-Reset: 0
X-Pagination-Total-Count: 0
X-Pagination-Page-Count: 0
X-Pagination-Current-Page: 1
X-Pagination-Per-Page: 10
Link: <https://XXX.YYY.ZZZ.WWW/glisapi/v1/pgrfas?doi=10.0155%2F1M&page=1&per-page=10>; rel=self
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 103
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pgrfas xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

As you can see in my cURL output I also have some headers.

I want to retrieve and store into two properties the values of the **X-Rate-Limit-Remaining** and of the **X-Rate-Limit-Reset** headers. Then I want to log these value into the Carbon console.

How can I do it? How can I extract these 2 values from the obtained response and put it into properties that will be logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `BLOCKING_SENDER_PRESERVE_REQ_HEADERS=false` just before call mediator, like this.

```
<property name="BLOCKING_SENDER_PRESERVE_REQ_HEADERS" value="false"/>
<call blocking="true">
    <endpoint key="xxxx"/>
</call>
<log level="full"/>
```

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Call+Mediator

Comment: Ok...but then how can I retrieve these values and put into properties?

Comment: and what exactly means the blocking="true" attribute on the call mediator? I am not using it in my code. What is the difference?

Comment: q1) I didn't check myself, but they should be available as properties of `transport` scope. 
q2) Please go to the link I gave and read the doc.

Comment: It seems to work using the $trp: scope without the <property name="BLOCKING_SENDER_PRESERVE_REQ_HEADERS" value="false"/>

Comment: in non-blocking mode?

Comment: You should be able to access transport headers liek this <property name="contentL" expression="$trp:Content-Length"></property>. So in your case <property name="myPropertyName" expression="$trp:X-Rate-Limit-Remaining"></property>